# What's the difference between the two expressions?

Tags: phrases

1. "Aadhar card is done here"
2. "Aadhar card done here"

Are the both correct?

Comment: They are both arguably incorrect.  Can you provide some context please?

Comment: @MaxWilliams outside a aadhar card centre it has been written "Aadhar card done here"

Comment: I don't think this question can be rescued with further context, as neither expression makes sense. I'm flagging it as off-topic ("belongs on ELL"). Hi Kumar, you may not be aware that this EL&U site is for "linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts", whereas your question is probably more suited to our other site [ell.se]. If you have a question for ELL, be sure to read their guidance on [what you can ask](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). :-)

Comment: British and American speakers will not know what "Aadhaar card" is. (Ministry of Electronics and Information Technology. **India**) I didn't until @Afaq answered. Next time, explain. Do not presume.

Answer (score 2):

Aadhaar is a 12-digit unique number issued by the Unique Identification Authority of India (UIDAI) by taking a person's biometric details such as iris scan and fingerprints, and demographic information like date of birth and address.

When they are saying Adhaar card done here they are referring to a process, so it's not wrong to say "Aadhar card is done here" or "Aadhar card done here"

both of them are correct.

for [reference](https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/wealth/personal-finance-news/aadhaar-everything-you-need-to-know-about-it/articleshow/60173210.cms)